# php fetch line by line result shows the last entry only

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to fetch data from database line by line in textarea

here the html code

```
<form action="show.php" target="my-iframe" method="post">

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment">

</textarea>

  <input type="submit" value="post">

</form>

<iframe name="my-iframe" src="show.php"></iframe>
```

here is the php

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '12345678', 'csv');
$text = trim($_POST['comment']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind

foreach ($textAr as $line) {
  $records3 = mysqli_query($db,"select * from `users` WHERE `here`='$line'");
  $data3 = mysqli_fetch_array($records3);
    echo trim($data3['aa']," ")."|".trim($data3['mm']," ")."|".trim($data3['xx']," ")."|".substr($data3['bb'], 2);
    echo "<br>";
    
}
```

the result only the last line is fetched from database.
plz help.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` fetches _one_ record from the result set. If you want to get all of them - then you need to use this in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Dear you have to use loop just like below where you are fetching the records.

```html
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '12345678', 'csv');
$text = trim($_POST['comment']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind

foreach ($textAr as $line) {
  $records3 = mysqli_query($db,"select * from `users` WHERE `here`='$line'");
  while($data3 = mysqli_fetch_array($records3))
{
    echo trim($data3['aa']," ")."|".trim($data3['mm']," ")."|".trim($data3['xx']," ")."|".substr($data3['bb'], 2);
    echo "<br>";
 }   
}
```